# Breaking JS String XSS

Tags: xss, web

I've been searching for XSS vulnerabilities in a friend's website (blackbox) and in one of the pages he takes your input and puts it inside a js script, `window.location="[INPUT]";` 
I couldn't break the quotes because they are being replaced with `&quot;` and `%22` stays `%22`, But I can put a `\` at the end of my input and it escapes the original quote (`window.location="[INPUT]\";`) Which gives me an unterminated string but I can't influence any code after that so there's no XSS there, right? All I can basicly do is break the code and that's it

Edit:
--Some more info--

1. `<`, `>`, `&` and `"` are being replaced with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`and `&quot;`
2. the server checks if `INPUT` begins with `http://` or `https://`

Things I've tried:

1. Break the string with `</script>` `=>` being replaced with `&lt;/script&gt;` (and fails)
2. Tried to break it with URL Encoded `</script>` (`%3C%2Fscript%3E`) but it shows it as string (`window.location = "http://test.com%3C%2Fscript%3E\";`) and the error is still `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

Comment: `window.location="javascript:alert(1)";`

Comment: @grc Can't, it checks if the input starts with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Even if this should not be exploitable, open redirects can be a vulnerability - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is not exploitable.**

- You cannot escape the string because quotes are encoded. (`"` -> `&quot;`)
- You cannot escape the script tag context because angle brackets are encoded. (`<` -> `&lt;`)
- You cannot create anything but `http[s]://` URLs because the beginning of the string is checked. It does not matter what you append after the protocol part, you cannot turn this into a `data:` or `javascript:` URL afterwards.

There are other tricks you could try but they are implementation-specific. There is no evidence they would work in this case, so these are just a few examples to give you an idea:

- Maybe the filter stops after a NULL byte? (e.g. `http://%00"<>...`)
- Maybe for some reason unicode variants work? (e.g. U+FF02: `＂`)
- Maybe other encoding schemes work? (e.g. `\x22` instead of `"`)
- etc.